# Making a vertical header horizontal

Tags: html, css, header

I'm trying to make the following horizontal along the page, instead of vertical. I would like to do this as it is meant to be a header along the top of the site. Thanks.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
        
li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
        
/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You haven't started a `<header>` but you have an end tag!

Comment: There's no `<html>`!

Comment: Downvote for error coding. No closing tag like </html>

Comment: Wow... why is stackoverflow so negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with you code:

- The `<header>` element is wrong, should be `<head>`.
- There's no `<html>` tag.
- The `</header>` is orphaned.
- There's no end tags for `</body>` and `</head>`.

Just do the two things:

- Remove the `width` for the `<ul>`.
- Add `display: inline-block` for the `<li>`.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }

      ul li {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      li a {
        display: block;
        color: #000;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      /* Change the link color on hover */
      li a:hover {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Added it, seems to work well. Thanks for the great help!

Answer (score 0):

try below css property for `li`

```
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors:
Look at this:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <style>
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
    /*            width: 200px;*/
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
            }
            li {display: inline-block}
            li a {
                display: block;
                color: #000;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            /* Change the link color on hover */

            li a:hover {
                background-color: #555;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add with `display:inline-block` its shows as horizontal and `width` will be auto its show as log. if you no need  the change width into px`

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:auto;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
 
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
li{display:inline-block;}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "display:inline-block" for the li.

```
<style>
 ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20%; /* put width as per your requirement*/
 }
</style>
```